# Shuffling in c++?

Tags: c++

Hello guys I just made a program that gets an input and if specific words in inputted it gives me a reply e.g If I write 'Hey' It replies me back and say 'Hello'. But I want it to give multiple replies randomly. For example 1st time it says hello and then how are you.
Can it be done in c++.

Comment: Do you want to give replies from pre defined replies or should it depend on the input. If it depends on input you are looking at artificial intelligence and simple approach won't work

Comment: Man shuffling ! It is done in php

Comment: Would you like to use each response once before seeing one again? If so, `std::shuffle`.

Comment: It can be done.  Depending on how you want it setup I would consider a [hash map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) of arrays that you could just select a random index on based on the reply.

Comment: "Can it be done in c++" - Yes it can. Next patient please.

Comment: I want that first time you compile it gives you different result and second time different while the input is same

Comment: `H2CO3!`
SHow me If you can! Doctor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let

```
char *text[20];
```

be your array of string

then you can pick up the string randomly by:

```
i = rand() % 20;
printf("%s", text[i]);
```

Comment: Would you also explain it to me?? What each line does? I can't get a single thing...

Comment: char *[20] declares array of strings. rand()%20 will output a number from 0 to 19 and will use that number as index into array of strings to print a random output

Comment: Man you are confusing me!!!

Comment: @FaizAhmed There's documentation for c++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/

Answer (score 0):

Just make a 2D array of charachter to store your replays and generate a random number to be the index of the picked replay:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // this is where srand and rand defined
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int picked;
    char *replay[3] = { // this is your list of replays
        "hey",
        "hello",
        "how are you",
        // ...
    };
    srand(time(NULL)); // seed for the pseudo-random number generator initialization
    picked = rand()%3; // rest of division by 3 so random integer bitween 0 and 2 
    printf("%s", replay[picked]); // then print the replay of the random picked index

    return 0;
}
```

Exemple code http://ideone.com/TAVG4j

For many executions this is the result:

```
Success  time: 0 memory: 2292 signal:0
hey
Success  time: 0 memory: 2248 signal:0
how are you
Success  time: 0 memory: 2292 signal:0
how are you
Success  time: 0 memory: 2292 signal:0
hey
Success  time: 0 memory: 2248 signal:0
hello
```

Comment: your comment is wrong: if you do a modulo 3 operation you will get an integer between 0 and 2 , not 0 and 3

Comment: Hey! What does these two lines means:
`srand(time(NULL));
    picked = rand()%3;`






`Starnd()` and `rand()` are also undefined and giving me an error!!!

Comment: Sorry you have to include `stdlib.h` see the code corrected!

Comment: rand() is generation a random number and by getting the rest of it's division by 2 we get a random number between 0 and 3. if you didn't call srand you will get the same random number each run because the pseudo-random number generator is initialized using the argument passed as seed. check this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/